# Python list simultaneous update

Tags: python, python-2.7

This seems to be a gotcha for me, I couldnt figure this out

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> tree = [Counter()]*3
>>> tree
[Counter(), Counter(), Counter()]
>>> tree[0][1]+=1
>>> tree
[Counter({1: 1}), Counter({1: 1}), Counter({1: 1})]
```

Why does updating one Counter updates everything?

Comment: Because of this line `[Counter()]*3`. You're not creating 3 unique Counters. You're creating one list with three references to the same Counter object.

Comment: You've got a list with three references to the same counter. Try a list comprehension instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `[x] * 3`, the list references same item(`x`) three times.

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> tree = [Counter()] * 3
>>> tree[0] is tree[1]
True
>>> tree[0] is tree[2]
True
>>> another_counter = Counter()
>>> tree[0] is another_counter
False

>>> for counter in tree: print id(counter)
...
40383192
40383192
40383192
```

Use list comprehension as Waleed Khan commented.

```
>>> tree = [Counter() for _ in range(3)]
>>> tree[0] is tree[1]
False
>>> tree[0] is tree[2]
False

>>> for counter in tree: print id(counter)
...
40383800
40384104
40384408
```

Comment: Also, `for counter in tree: print id(counter)` should give a better understanding.

Answer (score 1):

`[Counter()]*3` produces a list containing the *same* `Counter` instance 3 times. You can use

```
[Counter() for _ in xrange(3)]
```

to create a list of 3 independent `Counter`s.

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> tree = [Counter() for _ in xrange(3)]
>>> tree[0][1] += 1
>>> tree
[Counter({1: 1}), Counter(), Counter()]
```

In general, you should be cautious when multiplying lists whose elements are mutable.

Answer (score 1):

`tree = [Counter()]*3` creates one counter and three references to it; you could write it as:

```
c = Counter()
tree = [c, c, c]
```

You want three counters:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> tree = [Counter() for _ in range(3)]
>>> tree[0][1]+=1
>>> tree
[Counter({1: 1}), Counter(), Counter()]
>>>
```